# QIODevice::read (QSerialPort) : device not open

Tags: qt

I'm new with Qt Creator and I'm trying to read data from a light sensor communicating by I2C. I made a class `PortListener` that should return data received on the console once called.

```
PortListener::PortListener(const QString &portName)
{
this->port = new QSerialPort();
port->setPortName(portName);
port->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
port->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
port->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
port->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop); 
port->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl); 
port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QByteArray readData = port->readAll();
qDebug() << "message:" << readData;
}
```

But the only message I have is:

```
QIODevice::read (QSerialPort): device not open

message: ""
```

I don't understand what that mean?

Comment: You should check the value returned by `port->open(...)`.

Comment: It return me a _true_ value

Answer (score 1):

1.Open the serialport，then set the parameters.

```
PortListener::PortListener(const QString &portName)
{
   this->port = new QSerialPort();
   port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
   port->setPortName(portName);
   port->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
   port->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
   port->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
   port->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop); 
   port->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl); 
}
```

2.Connect the **readyRead** signal to a slot, and the slot is like this.

```
  void PortListener::readyReadSlot()
  {
      while (!port.atEnd()) {
          QByteArray data = port.readAll();
      }
  }
```

This is much more like the **QextSerialPort**, the following is the code from my application.

```
void SpClient::start()
{
    myComClient = new QextSerialPort(Setting::devCom);

    if(myComClient->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        qDebug() << "open " << Setting::devCom << "as client success";
    }
    myComClient->setBaudRate(BAUD9600);
    myComClient->setDataBits(DATA_8);
    myComClient->setParity(PAR_NONE);
    myComClient->setStopBits(STOP_1);
    myComClient->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
    myComClient->setTimeout(50);
    ....
}
```

Comment: @Robert I use serialport a lot ,I know the trick. This is the solution.

Comment: @Robert Ok, I will reorganize the code, and put on some of my code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to implement the code as you say but now I have the error message: QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::readyReadSlot()

Comment: @Quintinius You'd better describe the OS you use and the serialport name, that's important.

Comment: I connect signal by adding that line to PortListener:
> connect(port, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyReadSlot()));
And creating readyReadSlot:
void PortListener::readyReadSlot()
{
    while(!port->atEnd()){
        QByteArray data = port->readAll();
        qDebug() << "message :" << data;
    }
}

Comment: @Quintinius Your OS and serialport name, please.

Comment: I work on Windows 7 and I have connected sensors via an Arduino board on COM7 serial port

Comment: @Quintinius Make sure COM7 exist and is not used by other application.

Comment: COM7 is clearly visible on the control panel. To go further I did some tests with QextSerialPort library which give functional examples and it work! So the problem must come from my code

Comment: @Quintinius QextserialPort is reliable, but the question is still there. Forget this , continue your work.

Comment: So in your opinion I should give up QSerialPort and use QextSerialPort for my project ?

Comment: @Quintinius Yes, focus on your application.

Comment: Okay, I'll do like that. Thank you for your advices

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your code is failing to open the serial port, I have run into permissions issues under linux opening USB ports.  You will just need to do a chmod to grant your $USER access mostly.